# How would I POST from HTML using a button not a form for a MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, button

I posed a question previously but I think in the wrong way.

Currently I have a form submit that works to post "toggle_LED" but I want to avoid a form and only use a button to post from my HTML or PHP if possible? As I have a setup that checks for the post of "toggle_LED" for both a readout of what state the LED is in and another that switches the LED if the MySQL database is updated via a POST.

This is one place I want to use it for a little ESP_8266 project.

```
if (isset($_POST['toggle_LED'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM LED_status;";
    $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    
    if($row['status'] == 1){
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE LED_status SET status = 0 WHERE id = 1;");        
    }       
    else{
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE LED_status SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1;");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you unable to use a form? You can make a form that is completely invisible that is still able to do the POST request

Comment: A form can be resubmitted on refresh and I would like for that not to be possible in a cleaner way. Plus using a button generally seems cleaner but Im not too sure... Really am clueless on that front.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign a `dataset` attribute to your button you can easily toggle the value between `0` and `1` with a very simple piece of algebra - such as `state = 1 - state`

With that modified status value then send an ajax request to your php script to update the db.

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM LED_status;";
    $result   = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['status'], $_POST['task'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        if( $_POST['task']=='toggle_led' ){
            
            if( intval( $row['status'] ) == 1){
                $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE LED_status SET status = 0 WHERE id = 1;");        
            }else{
                $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE LED_status SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1;");        
            }
            
            exit( 'Database updated - status=' . $_POST['status'] );
        }
        
        exit();
    }
?>

<input type='button' name='toggle' value='Toggle LED' data-state=1 />

<script>
    let fd=new FormData();
    let bttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="toggle"]');
        bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            this.dataset.state = 1 - this.dataset.state;
            
            fd.set('status', this.dataset.state );
            fd.set('task', 'toggle_led');   // <---------- removed space!!!
            
            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd })
                .then(r=>r.text())
                .then(text=>alert(text))
            
            
        });
</script>
```

An alternative might be to do that same algebra in the database and not worry about the variable being sent.

ie:

```
$sql='UPDATE `LED_status` SET `status` = 1 - `status` WHERE `id` = 1';
```

Comment: The fact that your answer went straight over my head regarding the <script> for the button is maybe a sign that I need to study alot more. >_> Ill try and put it to use but if possible could you explain why you cant directly "post" with a button like you can with a form? I understand it is what it is but im not sure why...

Comment: `"you cant directly "post" with a button like you can with a form"` - a button is, by default, a `submit` button for a form. It's sole purpose is to submit a form - there can be no submission if there is no form which is why AJAX is your friend as there is no need for a form

Comment: AJAX sounds interesting will try and look into it. Hopefully thats a good solution.

Comment: I might be an idiot, but trying to get your solution to work always ends up with me having an error on my browser side with a popup that shows what the <script> portion of your solution states.

Comment: can you amend your question to show the new code or create a [pastebin paste](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link?

Comment: Ok - I think it is because it is the same page and I forgot to add `exit()` in the PHP.. will make changes now

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was rather busy yesterday. 

This is the current code trying to use what you sent me: https://pastebin.com/ShcjpRDL 

And this is the old code I was using, which works: https://pastebin.com/aS2NvbVV (I know it has the database password etc, ill change the info later) 

The current code uploaded to my domain is the old code as I was fiddling on the arduino side this morning.

Comment: The code in that first paste - that looks like it should be ok. Does that cause the error you mentioned?

Comment: Yea that causes an error where chrome has a pop-up with a bunch of code in it, would you like me to put that in a paste bin? 

On another note, this is the other file I have running for my arduino which is needed for things to work: https://pastebin.com/PcfZijs7 I dont think it would affect anything but decided to include it.

Comment: OK - It was a silly mistake where one of the javascript POST variables had a space at the end - so `fd.set('task', 'toggle_led ');` should be `fd.set('task', 'toggle_led');` - I'll make an amendment to the above and add some additional PHP to mitigate that mistook.

Comment: I imagine this might be used where there is more than one LED so I put together a working demo ( add own db details ) - [Pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/C9UZUrfk)

Comment: My man... you are an absolute god send in regards to me learning things but damn I need to learn more to understand how that works properly. 

Testing what you put in the last pastebin you linked, I think its working as intended and I think its connecting to the sql DB but its no longer updating the DB so ill try and find out why. But appreciate all the help, has been an eye opener on the direction I could go with things.